# Objective-C File Read

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm learning how to write simple Objective-C programs (without GUIs). I made a new xcode project and have the following files on the top-level directory:

```
main.m
data.txt
```

How can I get the contents of data.txt as an NSString for use in main.m?

I tried:

```
+ (NSString *)loadTextFileToString:(NSString*)fileDest {
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileDest
                                                     ofType:@"txt"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *fileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                     error:&error];
    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR while loading from file: %@", error);
    }
    return fileContent;
}
```

And passing @"data" as the argument but it gives me the error:

```
ERROR while loading from file: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=258 "The file name is invalid."
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is actually totally correct. The problem is with your XCode project. When you run your program, it gets run from the "Products" directory, the location of which depends on your XCode settings. If you want the data.txt file to end up in the same place as the executable, so it can be found at runtime, you need to add the file to the "Copy Files" build phase, with the destination set to the "Products" folder:

[image: How to copy a file in XCode 7]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Even with that picture, I can't figure out how to do that. How do I get to that screen in the first place (the one with build settings/build phases/build rules)?

Comment: Yeah, I probably could have cropped that better. On the left side of the main XCode window, click on the "Project Navigator", the left-most of the icons in the toolbar. Then click on the project icon at the top of the list of files in your project, and you'll see the project settings.

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. Thanks! Also worth noting that (at least in my situation where I was running from xcode directly) you also have to uncheck the box "copy only when installing" and remove the default subpath for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

Command line project, eh?

You'll want to pass the path to the file as an argument to the program and then use `[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments]` to grab the path.   You can't just name a file and hope that the working directory at runtime has any correspondence to where the file actually is; you need to specify a full path somehow.

Comment: Is that really the only solution? For example when working with java projects in eclipse I was able to use relative file paths starting with "src/". So if this was a java project I would do "new File("src/data.txt")" to load the file data.txt in the top-level directory of my project. Is there something similar I can do with xcode/objective-c?

Comment: @kmell96 It all depends on where the "current working directory" is when the tool is run.  If you pass "src/data.txt" as the filepath, then that path will be interpreted as relative to that CWD.  When testing command line tools, I usually just provide a full path in the arguments pane or I provide ~/testfiles/project/foo.txt and keep my sample data there.a